# R: Appending to a data frame in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, append

So I have this loop, and it writes multiple csv files, with each one having been appended out of the results of the run. As you can see below, this particular loop runs a statistical function (zScore) across each row of an subset from gex against mxy, then publishes the results for each row, then moves onto the next subset of gex.

My question is, instead of writing the appended result as a csv file, is there a way that I can just build a dataframe within the loop that looks the same?

Thank you for your kind help.

```
gex <- data.frame("sample" =  c("BIX","HEF","TUR","ZOP","VAG"), 
                  "TCGA-F4-6703-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-DM-A28E-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AY-6197-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-A6-5657-01" = runif(5, -1, 1))
colnames(gex) <- gsub("[.]", "_",colnames(gex))

listx <- c("TCGA_DM_A28E_01","TCGA_A6_5657_01")

mxy <- data.frame("TCGA-AD-6963-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AA-3663-11" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AD-6901-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-AZ-2511-01" = runif(5, -1, 1),
                  "TCGA-A6-A567-01" = runif(5, -1, 1)) 

colnames(mxy) <- gsub("[.]", "_",colnames(mxy))

zScore <- function(x,y)((as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(rowMeans(y,na.rm=T)))/as.numeric(sd(y,na.rm=T)))

   for(i in seq(nrow(mxy))){
      for(colName in listx){
        zvalues <- zScore(gex[i,colName],
                          mxy[i,])
        geneexptest <- data.frame(gex$sample[i], zvalues, row.names = NULL, 
                                  stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
        write.table(geneexptest, file = paste0(colName, "mxyinput", ".csv"),
                    row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE,  quote=F,
                    sep = ",", dec = ".", append=(i > 1))
      }
    }
```

Comment: Declare a dataframe outside of the loop, then use `rbind` or `cbind` to add row(s) or column(s) in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Hey @SamFirke, thanks for the feedback - how do I "declare a dataframe outside of the loop" while still utilizing each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @SamFirke this is generally quite inefficient in R -- check out Circle 2 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the link @josilber, I know to avoid for-loops in R generally but wasn't aware of the memory implications.  @HenriW, see josilber's solution; you could create a data frame at first like he does, then append to on each iteration of the loop using an `rbind` call - but his solution w/ `lapply` is better as he explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted code you have one csv file for each element of `listx`, and you are writing a number of lines one-by-one into each of these files. Instead, you could create a data frame for each element of `listx` and write each out with a single call to `write.table`.

```
dfs <- lapply(listx, function(colName) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(mxy)), function(i) {
    zvalues <- zScore(gex[i,colName], mxy[i,])
    data.frame(gex$sample[i], zvalues, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  }))
})
dfs
# [[1]]
#   gex.sample.i.    zvalues
# 1           BIX  1.1105593
# 2           HEF  0.5451948
# 3           TUR -1.4060388
# 4           ZOP -1.4218218
# 5           VAG  0.2780513
# 
# [[2]]
#   gex.sample.i.   zvalues
# 1           BIX 2.0607386
# 2           HEF 1.6703912
# 3           TUR 1.3249181
# 4           ZOP 0.8865058
# 5           VAG 1.5289732
```

Now you can output the full data frame for each column using `write.table`.

Combining all the data frames together in a single call to `rbind` will be much more efficient than calling `rbind` at each loop iteration; see Circle 2 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for more details.

Comment: I understand your changes in terms of efficiency, but it is not compiling things the way I'd like. My problem is that, as you can see in the OP, I write `geneexptest` every time I construct it. The key there is the `append=(i > 1)` option in `write.table`. I want to do the same exact thing, but manipulate geneexptest (in its appended form...) into another dataframe and THEN write it out to a csv. (Then move on to next round, etc). Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: @HenriW this code appends every single `geneexptest` into a single data frame. You could just write it out to a file at the end with `write.table`. Unfortunately your original post is not reproducible (I can't run your code as posted) so it's tough to exactly replicate its functionality. I would encourage you to update your question to make it reproducible if you need more help.

Comment: I've attached some stuff to build the relevant inputs - please let me know what you think. So, I would like it to have the same functionality, but with the possibility of including some additional manipulation BEFORE each round is outputted in `write.table`. That's why I asked about appending dataframes within a for loop.

Comment: @HenriW I've updated my code based on your updated question. This really highlights the importance of posting a reproducible example of your problem in your questions on SO.

Comment: Very helpful!! So, one last thing: I am attempting to modulate things inside the loop, which is now shown in a supplement to the original post. There, you can see that the last `data.frame(...)` is attempting to produce `geneexptotal`, not `geneexptest` as before. However, what is being produced is actually `geneexptestapp`. Is there a reason that it stops short at that point?

Comment: @HenriW in general it's best to ask new questions if you have new programming problems instead of editing an old one -- this makes sure the entire community sees your new problem. If my answer has solved your original question I would encourage you to accept it and ask a new question with your new problem.